# Trying to create multiple lines chart Rstudio

Tags: r, plot

Hi I am trying to create a multiple coloured line graph based on three lines.

Essentially I have data that identifies different people by the variable Person_Index. I want to create a plot with differently coloured lines for each Person_Index identity.

[The following is a screen shot of the data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBimG.png)

The following is a snippet of my code I am trying to accomplish this with. (Sorry I was having trouble with the formatting and so had to include it as an image)

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9fFS.png)

However when I go to plot, I get this?

[Plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD51g.png)

It is plotting all of the points. But it is not separating them by the person_index ID's. What am I missing? And also how do I get Rstudio to return the trend line equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you aren't indexing the data by the person. So it is just plotting all the data again and again. You could do something like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(PersonID_num))) {
  lines(Timestamp_num[PersonID_num==unique(PersonID_num)[i]], 
        boundx[PersonID_num==unique(PersonID_num)[i]], type = "b", lwd = 1.5, lty = linetype[i], col = colors[i])
}
```

Alternatively, it might be more convenient to use `ggplot2`. There, you can specify a dataframe with your timestamps, boundx and people IDs and then do something along the lines of

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Timestamp_num, y = boundx, color = PersonID_num)) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems OP is looking for a base `plot` library based solution. I have created similar `data.frame` which has got slightly different values.

```
#Data
df <- data.frame( person_index = c(1,1,0,2,0,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,1,1,1,0),
                  timestamp = c(300, 350, 375, 380, 385, 395, 399, 410, 425, 430, 442, 450, 455, 460, 499, 510),
                  Xmiddle = c(550, 600, 610, 620, 500, 700, 650, 800, 750, 850, 725, 786, 765, 500, 700, 750))

# Segregate the datasets for each index
index_0 <- which(df$ person_index == 0)
index_1 <- which(df$ person_index == 1)
index_2 <- which(df$ person_index == 2)

#First draw for index_0 using plot. The range is on whole date
plot(df$timestamp[index_0], df$Xmiddle[index_0], type = "o", pch = 1,
     xlim = range(df$timestamp), ylim = range(df$Xmiddle),
     xlab = "Time", ylab = "xmiddle")

#Draw for index_1. Using lines
lines(df$timestamp[index_1], df$Xmiddle[index_1], type = "o", pch = 2)

#Draw for index_2. Using lines
lines(df$timestamp[index_2], df$Xmiddle[index_2], type = "o", pch = 16)

legend("topleft", pch = c(1, 2, 16), legend = c("Index 0", "Index 1", "Index 2"))
```

[image]